# How to access RecyclerView adapter itemView items?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a recycle view and I manage to access each item view (for example to set color) by using

```
recycler_view.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red)
```

However, I also have a button on each item (secondary action).

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lines_container">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_text_view"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="@{contact.status.active ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/secondary_action"/>
```

How can I access the secondary action button/imageView with the 'position' I have?

Comment: `recycler_view.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondary_action)`

Comment: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : View!> findViewById(p0: Int): T!
Please specify it explicitly.

Comment: recycler_view.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.secondary_action)

Comment: Yes I think it works! many many thanks!

Comment: No. You need to modify the dataset, then notify the adapter that a given item has changed. If you're just changing values in the view holder's views, you'll scroll it out of the screen and scroll it back and booom it's broken again.